# Puppet: what's wrong with my configuration?

Tags: puppet

I want to learn puppet.
Installation on Suse ok.
The CA and SSL works fine

```
puppet cert list --all
```

Return my master and my client.

On client

```
puppet agent -t
```

Return OK,no problem.

I start a very simple manifest,hello world,I want to apply on master and client.

```
file { '/tmp/hello-world.txt':
        ensure => file,
        content => "hello, world\n",
}
```

Do on master

```
puppet apply manifest.pp
```

On client

```
puppet agent -t
```

On master I see the hello world file,on client not.
This is my puppet.conf on master and client

```
#master

[master]
vardir = /opt/puppetlabs/server/data/puppetserver
logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
codedir = /etc/puppetlabs/code
dns_alt_names = suse3.mynet.priv,suse3

[main]
certname = suse3.mynet.priv,suse3
server = suse3.mynet.priv,suse3
environment = production
runinterval = 1h

#Client
[main]
certname = suse2.mynet.priv
server = suse3.mynet.priv
environment = production
runinterval = 1h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: manifests were in wrong dir.
Must be on dir

```
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests
```